# How to delete only one field from mongodb in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have been looking through all the questions but eventhough it should be something common, I did not see any question like that. So, I have a data in my db like that, I would like to delete only token field after a specific timeout in nodejs. I thought using deleteOne method but it deletes the whole data. I need to keep the data other than the token. Thanks

```
{
 "_id": "samplesample",
 "item":{},
 "password": "$2a$10$vsB.X7OZIv1464PX38wj2OZ9it7lxCtToM4CxQx8MANy1GzluTEmy",
 "token": "b166VSe1vdpUMe9S"
}
```

Comment: Use [`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) and write your own scheduling code. There is no "built-in" scheduler aside from the handling of TTL indexes, which is "document removal" and indeed not this.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how did not I see that. I 'll take a look!

Comment: Probably a good idea when you need to know something to try searching for it first https://www.google.com/q=mongodb+remove+field since the top results are basically what you just got pointed to.